# Debian: create user during packaging

Tags: build, debian

I'm repackaging some software (which has its own installer) for private use under a Debian-based system. That software is already compiled (no source), so I basically run the installer into the `$DESTDIR` tree.

Unfortunately, the installer requires that a system username and groupname is previously created. Now, I know it is a simple matter of doing it "by hand" prior to building (and installing) the Debian package. But I'm wondering if it is possible to instruct debuild to "fake the creation of a user" (while running as root with fakeroot). Editing the `debian/preinst.ex` and `debian/postrm.ex` files works for doing those operations, but this also concerns the **build** stage, where those users become unnecessary after the build.

So basically this ammounts to let the Debian build tools (and tools run within the build) to "believe" that a certain user already exists. Short of running in a chroot-ed environment (such as pbuilder), how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but my best guess would be an `LD_PRELOAD`, which requires building a separate C-file compiled to a dynamic library which can override e.g. `getpwnam()` which is probably what the installer uses to check for the user.

But first, I would **really** look to see if the "installer" can't be coerced into unpack-mode. Many installers can, using hidden options.